# Distinguishing iPad with Retina Display and iPad2

Tags: ipad

Tomorrow I will buy a 2nd hand iPad with Retina Display. But I do not have an idea how I can distinguish it from ipad 2. I know retina display is a very significant difference for experienced users. However I have never used an ipad 2 or ipad 1 so I cannot understand the difference.

What is the best way to distinguish two of them? It seems like there does not exist any logo like ipad 2 or ipad with retina display on the back of the device. Is there a way to understand it from settings menu or somewhere else?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serial numbers (on the back in small print, near the bottom) will be different depending on the model. If you check [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3821827?start=0&tstart=0) you can write down the model number for the version you're buying, in case you're worried about getting scammed. The iPad 3 model numbers all begin with A14.